# Records duplicated managing form submit within a popover from Meteor

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, meteor, popover

My Meteor app has a popover which lists tasks completed by people on a team. Team members can signal a new task completion simply opening the popover, filling out the input field and then pressing the enter key.
It happens that, for some reason, the form submit event is fired more than once and then I got duplicated records in my Mongodb.

This is my code:

```
Template.header.onRendered(function() {
  $("#sneak-preview-btn").popover({
    container: 'body',
    template: '<div class="popover work-journals-popover" role="tooltip"><div class="arrow"></div><h3 class="popover-title"></h3><div class="popover-content"></div></div>',
    animation: true,
    placement : 'right',
    html : true,
    delay: { "show": 500, "hide": 100 },
    trigger : 'manual',
    content : function() {
      var popTitle = "<h5>Peek last 5 activities completed by your team mates.</h5>";
      var formAddEntry = "<form id='add-entry'><div class='form-group'><input id='entry' name='entry' type='text' class='form-control' placeholder='Add a new task you completed'/></div></form>";
      var entriesLimit = 5;
      var htmlEntryList = "";
      var myEntries =  WorkJournals.find({userId : Meteor.userId()}, {sort : {createdAt : -1}, limit : entriesLimit}).fetch();

      if (myEntries) {
        htmlEntryList ="<div class='scroll-journal-entries'><ul>";
        myEntries.map(function(en) {
          htmlEntryList += libGetHtmlJournalEntry(en);
        });
        htmlEntryList += "</ul>";
        var companyUsers = Profiles.find({companyId : libGetCompanyIdFromUser(Meteor.userId())}, {fields : {userId : 1}}).fetch();
        companyUsers.filter(function(user) {
          if (user.userId !== Meteor.userId())
            htmlEntryList += libGetHtmlJournalEntries(user.userId, entriesLimit);
        });

        htmlEntryList += "</div>";
      }
      return "<div>" + popTitle + formAddEntry + "<p>" + htmlEntryList + "</p><button id='close-sneak-preview' type='button' class='btn btn-default btn-xs pull-right'>Close</button><br>" + "</div>";
    }
  });
  //manage lost focus
  $(document).on('blur', '.popover', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $("#sneak-preview-btn").popover('hide');
  });

  //manage submit
  $(document).on('submit', '#add-entry', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    WorkJournals.insert({
      companyId: Profiles.findOne({userId : Meteor.userId()}).companyId,
      userId : Meteor.userId(),
      entryText : $('#entry').val(),
      createdAt : new Date().getTime()
    });
    $("#sneak-preview-btn").popover('hide');
    libShowAlert('messages-heading-row', 'A completed task was added to your activity log', 'alert-nice');
  });

  $(document).on('click', "#close-sneak-preview", function() {
    $("#sneak-preview-btn").popover('hide');
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This doesn't look very Meteor to me. You have a template, yet register events with the document? Can it be that on multiple renders of your header template the $(document) events accumulate, so you end up with a whole chain of those?

Comment: Form submit in the popovet was not trapped at template level, that's why I was forced to use $(document)

Comment: Have you tried calling the button submit on template level instead?

Comment: I moved as submit code outside onRendered and it seems to work – more test is needed. Thanks. It would be great to find a pattern to use form submit in a popover a bit more Meteor compliant but for now I couldn't fine one. Maybe I should replace popover with a modal dialog

Comment: I use form submits in bootstrap modals all the time. You need to be careful mixing regular jQuery paradigms with Meteor blaze templates.